# Discover network switches in a network

Tags: networking, ethernet, discovery

I want to discover switches in my network to build the network topology.
Right now, storage devices are discovered via SMI providers. Is there any way to discover switches through SMI, SNMP or other technique?

Comment: Switches are transparent devices. Some switches can have management addresses, but they may not even be on the same networks as the hosts.

Answer (score 0):

99% of our customers discover networks from a "hint" you give to the discovery algorithm: a seed device (eg. router) that contains some information that the algorithm retrieves via a management protocol, eg. SNMP or CLI (command line interface) or REST or NetFlow, then traverses the returned directed graph to retrieve interconnected devices. All of this assumes that you have access to those devices.